# Recorrer array accediendo a atributos de clases hijas

Tags: java, array, herencia

Tengo un arreglo de tipo `Relacion`, que esta lleno de objetos de tipo `Binario`.

`Binario` hereda de `Relacion`. ¿Como puedo obtener los valores de los atributos de los objetos de tipo binario?

```
  Relacion exprs[] = { new Binario(Operador.MENORQUE,
                                new Falso(),
                                new Verdadero()),
                       new Binario(Operador.MAYORQUE,
                                   new Falso(),
                                   new Verdadero()),
                       new Binario(Operador.MENORQUE,
                                   new Verdadero(),
                                   new Verdadero()),
                       new Binario(Operador.MAYORQUE,
                                   new Verdadero(),
                                   new Falso())
  };
```

Clase relacion

```
 public abstract class Relacion {
 }
```

Clase Binario:

```
  public class Binario extends Relacion {

   private Relacion izq;
   private Relacion der;
   private Operador oper;

 public Binario(Operador oper, Relacion izq, Relacion der) {

    this.oper = oper;
    this.izq  = izq;
    this.der  = der;
 }

 public Relacion obtIzq() {

    return this.izq;
 }

 public Relacion obtDer() {

    return this.der;
 }

 public Operador obtOper() {

    return this.oper;
 }
}
```

Comment: Necesitas recorrer el array obteniendo los valores de los atributos de sus elementos? Podrias colocar el codigo de la clase Relacion y de la clase Binario?

Comment: ya los coloco, y si necesito recorrey el array obteniendo los valores

Comment: Si el arreglo solo va a tener valores de tipo `Binario`, ¿no sería mejor que tu arreglo sea `Binario[] exprs` en lugar de `Relacion[] exprs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu array está definido sobre el tipo `Relación`, por lo que puedes acceder a los atributos y métodos de dicha clase, no la de sus clases hijas.

Para poder acceder a miembros de las clases hijas de `Relación` debes [castear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java) a una de esas clases, por ejemplo, `Binario`

La operación de casteo no es una operación segura y puede derivar en [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) en tiempo de ejecución.

**Ejemplo:**

```
public class Vehiculo{
 }

public class Auto extends Vehiculo{
     public void abrirPuertas(){
     }
 }

public class Moto extends Vehiculo{
     public void wheele(){
     }
 }
```

Situacion donde castear produciria ClassCastException:

```
List<Vehiculo> vehiculos = new ArrayList<Vehiculo>();
vehiculos.add(new Moto());
vehiculos.add(new Auto());

for(Vehiculo v : vehiculos){
   Moto m = (Moto) v; //Casteo
   m.wheele();
}
```

La primera iteracion del bucle no tendría inconvenientes, ya que el primer vehículo agregado es efectivamente una `Moto`, sin embargo, en la segunda iteración se intentaria castear un `Auto` a `Moto` y como `Auto` no es subtipo de `Moto` se produce ClassCastException.

**Como castear y acceder a miembros de clases hijas de manera segura?**

Utilizando el operador [instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java) para primero chequear si el tipo concreto de la variable de iteración es `Binario` previo a realizar la operación de casteo:

```
for(Relacion rel : exprs){
     if(rel instanceof Binario){ // chequeo si rel es Binario.
         Binario bin = (Binario) rel; // si es Binario puedo castear
         // acceso a sus miembros y metodos
         bin.obtIzq(); 
         bin.obtDer();
         bin.obtOper();
     }
}
```